# install a service on a remote computer from a MSBuild script

Tags: .net, msbuild, teamcity, msbuild-task

I have this task that creates a service:

Target Name="InstallService" DependsOnTargets="CopyFiles"
Exec Command="sc \ \remotecomputer create "ServiceHost" binPath= "E:\ServiceHost.exe" DisplayName= "ServiceHost""
WorkingDirectory="c:\" ContinueOnError="false" 
/Target

The problem is that when I run this script it doesn't know the \ \remotecomputer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out: you have to use it like this: """\ \remotecomputer"""